# How to enforce id on angular 2+ downgraded component?

Tags: angular, migration

I'm migrating AngularJS 1.6 components to Angular 4.3.2 and need to enforce an `id` attribute on the component tag. However to make ng2+ work with existing ng1 components, you need to downgrade them:

```
angular.module('myNg1module')
  .directive('myComponent', downgradeComponent({component: MyComponent}))
```

In the compiled output, this makes [Angular generate a dynamic id](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/upgrade/src/common/downgrade_component.ts#L67) which overrides your own `id`. For example the output will be:

```
<my-component id="NG2_UPGRADE_27_0"></my-component>
```

What I tried without success:

- set the `id` attribute in the template: `<my-component id="my-id">` but the output will simply overwrite it ;
- set the id through `[attr.id]` in the template: `<my-component [attr.id]="my-id">` but this will be ignored.

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Answer (score 1):

If not a real solution to what is [an Angular bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18446), here is the workaround I used to overwrite the generated `id`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component'
})
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.el.nativeElement.id = this.id;
  }
}
```

then invoke `<my-component [id]="my-id">`

It looks that the overwriting of such a generated id [won't have bad side-effects](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18446#issuecomment-319323816).